# C++14 tuple addressing by type - isn't it just making a generally-invalid assumption?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

The [C++14 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) describes the new language feature of [tuple addressing by type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Variable_templates), with which you could do write:

```
tuple<string, string, int> t("foo", "bar", 7);
int i = get<int>(t);        // i == 7
```

Well, generally, this fails, i.e. in the general case a tuple has more than one element of the same type. It's a pretty specific (albeit common, I admit) kind of tuples which have one-value-per-type; and this kind of a get sort of implies the semantic of `get<T>(t)` being sort of the `T`-representation of `t`, as though the values in different types are somehow related.

Why is it a good idea to have such a method, which does not apply in the general case, and seems to be relevant to some, well, I guess you could say subclasses of the tuples?

Comment: It is nice in the cases where it works, and you don't have to use it the rest of the time. Does it really hurt?

Answer (score 6):

I think the primary motivation is that addressing a `std::tuple` by position is not very readable or nor very robust; from the [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3404.html):

> Suppose we have a function get_employee_info that returns some employee information in a tuple. Saying something like get<2>(get_employee_info(...) doesn't really make it that obvious that we are looking for the employee's office. Furthermore, if we later become interested in returning another employee attribute, we may need to adjust indexes all over the program.

Of course, this can only be done for unique types. However, one could use, for example, enum classes, lightweight wrappers for things like `std::string`, etc. to make these easier to read and maintain.

Here's a quick example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct FirstName : std::string { using std::string::basic_string; };
struct LastName : std::string { using std::string::basic_string; };

struct EmployeeID
{
    EmployeeID(int id) : employeeID_m(id) { }
    operator int() const { return employeeID_m; }
    const EmployeeID &operator=(int id) { employeeID_m = id; return *this; }
    int employeeID_m;
};

using Record = std::tuple<FirstName, LastName, EmployeeID>;

void printRecord(const Record &r)
{
    std::cout << std::get<FirstName>(r) << " "
        << std::get<LastName>(r)
        << "'s employee ID is "
        << std::get<EmployeeID>(r)
        << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    Record record1 = std::make_tuple(FirstName("Slim"), LastName("Jim"), EmployeeID(12233));
    Record record2 = std::make_tuple(FirstName("Big"), LastName("Bill"), EmployeeID(33221));

    printRecord(record1);
    printRecord(record2);

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
Slim Jim's employee ID is 12233
Big Bill's employee ID is 33221
```

Comment: I don't really see how addressing it by type is more robust. And if you want clarity - you would use a struct with named fields anyway. I'm not really buying it as a reason.

Comment: It supports a different style of programming, that's all. For instance, if I add an "age" field as a wrapped "int" I don't have to modify old code to account for the rearrangement of the fields in the `tuple`.

Comment: It only support this 'different style' if it's a tuple with unique types. Or if you make them unique. But if you've done that, well - just use something other than a tuple. What can I say, I'm not convinced...

Comment: Not trying to convince you, just explaining why it was done. I think there are many uses where this will be clearer. You could *always* use a struct - support for tuples didn't add anything new to the language in terms of overall capability. Just a different style that I think appeals to many functional programmers.

Comment: I think this is pretty nice. Ordering by number if fragile for the same reasons you don't want to number struct members by number in the first place. One benefit of a tuple over a struct is that you *can* loop over the tuple, concatenate it, etc with template meta programming. Also, the idiom used for FirstName, LastName is anyway a standard one.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: Again, this is relevant only for the very limited case of not having 2 values of the same type. I can't understand how come a language feature is added for just this case. An employee with first name and last name, salary in dollars and age in years? Can't get any of these fields...